Gauge java is getting Killing runner with PID:XXX forcefully
I am running tests using gauge on my jenkins node.
My shell script at some point runs :
/usr/local/bin/gauge run specs

I am reaching a point where the output is :
Successfully generated html-report to => /mydirectory/html-report/index.html

Killing runner with PID:XXXX forcefully
Specifications: 1 executed  1 passed    0 failed    0 skipped
Scenarios:  1 executed  1 passed    0 failed    0 skipped

The problem is that I have this running on two different jenkins nodes. one is a cloud VM and one is a local VM.
Both of them generates the report and performs the test. but the one with Killing runner with PID:XXXX forcefully takes some minutes more until the kill happens. I can't figure out where to troubleshoot.

I am not just thinking that maybe updating gauge or html-report would help. but very weird that no one has had such an issue before
